# Amazon EC2 vs Shared Hosting for Website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, shared-hosting

I've a website that can have on an average half million views per month. Due to some limitations in shared hosting, I need to consider EC2 or some some VPS. However, among VPS, I'm feeling EC2 is reliable as I have to use it along with a Amazon SES (Will go more performance because of same location). I'm trying to find if I can host such a website with reasonable response time on EC2 t1.micro instance. Please let me know. If not, please suggest some alternatives

Comment: I never use Amazon but if I read the services, it almost same with VPS. If your site consume high resources, then it is recommended to use VPS.

Answer (score 1):

EC2 is in many ways like a VPS, with some tools that you probably wont find at most VPS providers.

You will probably not get half a million views on a micro unless they were very spread out during the day. Micros use a burstable architecture, you get 2 ECU worth of computing power, then you get locked to way less than 1 ECU for a while afterwards.